# Remove column in datatable

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am exporting a datatable to an excel sheet successfully... In that excel sheet i have to display the columns(customerid,Productname,referenceno) of the data table except the last column.... now how can i display the data table in excel without display the last column(referenceno)...

anyone tell me the solution of this problem..
Thanks in Advance..

here is my code for export datatable to excel:

```
         System.Data.DataTable dt = clsobj.convert_datagrid_orderlist_to_datatable(dvgorderlist, txtreferenceno);

        oxl = new Excel.Application();
        oxl.Visible = true;
        oxl.DisplayAlerts = false;

        wbook = oxl.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        oxl.ActiveCell.set_Item(2, 4, "Alfa Aesar");

        wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbook.ActiveSheet;

        wsheet.Name = "Customers";
        Excel.Range range = wsheet.get_Range("A6", "H6");

        wsheet.get_Range("A6", "H6").Font.Name = "Times new Roman";
        wsheet.get_Range("A6", "H6").Font.Size = 12;
        wsheet.get_Range("A6", "H6").Interior.Color = ConvertColour(Color.SkyBlue);

        oxl.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

        int rowCount = 5;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            rowCount += 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                // Add the header the first time through
                if (rowCount == 7)
                {
                    wsheet.Cells[6, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;

                }
                wsheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
                Excel.Range cellRange = (Range)wsheet.Cells[rowCount, i];
                //cellRange.Interior.Color = 200;
                //cellRange.Interior.Color = ConvertColour(Color.LightBlue);
                cellRange.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            }


        }

        cells = wsheet.get_Range(wsheet.Cells[2, 2],
                      wsheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);
        cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();


        wsheet = null;
        cells = null;
```

Comment: Do you wish to hide it in excel, or not set the column at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for statement change this line

```
 for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
```

with this one

```
var filteredColumns = dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
         .Where( x=> x.ColumnName != "referenceno" );
              foreach (var column in filteredColumns )
{
     //do whatever you want 
             //if you need the index you can create counter and increase it by 1 each loop 
}
```

don't forget to use linq

```
using System.Linq ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
dt.Columns.Remove[dt.Columns.Count - 1];
```

Comment: thanks for post ur answer... but this code is not working... and how this line findout that particlular column?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    bool deleteIt = true;
    foreach (StringDictionary sd in sdArray)
    {
        if (dc.ColumnName.Equals(sd["Name"]))
            deleteIt = false;
    }
    if (deleteIt)
        data.Columns.Remove(dc);
}
```

`sdArray` contains all the columns you want in your Excel worksheet. If you prefer you could use a normal `string[]` instead. I used an array of `StringDictionaries` because I have more information per row, such as width.

Linq is also very awesome to use for this kinds of tasks, but the example above only supports one row. So I figured we needed some diversity.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Worksheet.get_Range("rangeVal", "rangeVal").EntireColumn.Hidden = true;`

Answer (score 0):

dt.Columns.Remove[ColumnIndex];

Or

dt.Columns.Remove["ColumnName"];

try any ...