# Delete column and its values from datatable using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have a requirement like this:

I want to delete a particular column name and its corresponding values from Datatable. For example:

```
Column-A

AB

VG

DT
```

I want to remove Column-A and its all the three values.

I am using C# ASP.NET and also LINQ.

Please answer regading to C# and LINQ.

Comment: as you have not mentioned in details, I can only provide you the query for **deleting column** from the table `ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP COLUMN COLUMN_NAME`

Comment: table.Columns.Remove("col");

Comment: you can select only needed columns instead delete it from result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove column in datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425296/remove-column-in-datatable)

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck if i do only remove..its removing the column name but not its corresponding values.

Comment: doesn't deletion of column requires dropping the table?

Comment: @FelixAv i want to delete a particular column name and its corresponding values in a datatable

Comment: I see, check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
dataTableName.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

The values will be deleted automatically.